# Testing point in the alpha channel

Tags: iphone, flash, opengl-es, alpha

Is there a way to detect if the alpha of a pixel after drawing is not 0 when using OpenGLES on the iphone?

I would like to test multiple points to see id they are inside the area of a random polygon drawn by the user. If you know Flash, something equivalent to BitmapData::getPixel32 is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Doesn't BitmapData::getPixel32 return the alpha channel value?

Comment: getPixel32 returns the full ARGB value of a pixel. From that you can detect if there's something or not on that pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framebuffer is kept by the GPU and is not immediately CPU accessible. I think the thing you'd most likely want from full OpenGL is the occlusion query; you can request geometry be drawn and be told how many pixels were actually plotted. Sadly that isn't available on the iPhone.

I think what you probably want is glReadPixels, which can be used to read a single pixel if you prefer, e.g. (written here, as I type, not tested)

```
GLubyte pixelValue[4];
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelValue);

NSLog(@"alpha was %d", pixelValue[3]);
```

Using glReadPixels causes a pipeline flush, so is generally a bad idea from a GL performance point of view, but it'll do what you want. Unlike iOS, OpenGL uses graph paper order for pixel coordinates, so (0, 0) is the lower left corner.

Comment: It does work, and it is also affecting performance greatly. I tried to load all pixels at once, but it is still slow. Is there a way to take just the alpha channel to speed things off?

Comment: I've discovered subsequently that you can specify GL_ALPHA as the format rather than GL_RGBA and have just that channel returned. I'm not sure it'd make much difference to performance though — it's calling glReadPixels at all that's a problem. If you're doing multiple tests, I think it could be faster to use glReadPixels to grab the entire display at once, then check alpha values from that.